# Spring (Integration) Kafka Consumer fails to consume all messages if under back pressure

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

We are at the moment struggling with some difficulties concerning our Kafka setup and the consuming Java listeners.

## Setup

We have three different components all together deployed as Spring Boot application in one Tomcat container, lets call them source, processor and sink.

- The source is invoked via REST, ingests messages and produces Kafka messages for a topic A (with 9 partitions).
- The processor consumes messages from Kafka topic A, enriches and filters them and finally produces Kafka messages for a second topic B (with 9 partitions).
- The sink consumes messages from Kafka topic B and channels them to another system via REST call which is not performing very well.

We only have one Kafka Broker at the moment.

## The Problem

If there is high pressure on the source in terms of a lot of REST calls to the first component the source - e.g. 1000 requests in 15 seconds - the downstream component processor processes all the created messages but the sink fails to consume some of them so the Kafka lag starts to grow (maybe because of the slow system to which the sink sends REST calls) and the consumer fails to handle them.
But they do exist in the topic (B in this case)!

We tried to handle this situation by trying to tune the parameters *session.timeout.ms* and *max.poll.records*, but without reaching a lag of 0 / consuming all messages in the sink.

In my opinion I thought that the consumer would handle every message or would at least log some error but non of that happens unfortunately.

Further, we mocked the system that gets called by the sink and is thus performing better and then the problems where getting better.

Okay we managed to reproduce the problem in a more simplistic way and started to monitor the application with yourkit.

For the configuration below we have four times the two components:

- org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-x-kafka-listener-x
- org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-x-kafka-consumer-x

at some point in time one or more of the kafka-listeners are waiting indefinitely and their Threads stay in sun.misc.Unsafe.park(...) forever.

The question is why do they do that?

In my opinion even if the consumers are slow, all the messages should be consumed eventually!

## CONT

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-kafka-listener-1 State: SLEEPING tid: 23
java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) Thread.java
de.foobar.eventing.business.GenericTopicConsumer.process(String, byte[]) GenericTopicConsumer.java:60
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Object, Object[])
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object[]) Method.java:498
org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(Object[]) InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180
org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(Message, Object[]) InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112
org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(Message, Object[]) HandlerAdapter.java:48
org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(Object, Acknowledgment, Message) MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:174
org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(ConsumerRecord, Acknowledgment) RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:72
org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(Object, Acknowledgment) RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:47
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(ConsumerRecords) KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:764
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(ConsumerRecords) KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:708
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$2500(KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer, ConsumerRecords) KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:230
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run() KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:975
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() Executors.java:511
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() FutureTask.java:266
java.lang.Thread.run() Thread.java:745

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-kafka-listener-2 State: WAITING tid: 22
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) Unsafe.java
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) LockSupport.java:215
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit) LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run() KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:971
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() Executors.java:511
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() FutureTask.java:266
java.lang.Thread.run() Thread.java:745

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-2-kafka-listener-1 State: WAITING tid: 24
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) Unsafe.java
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) LockSupport.java:215
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit) LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run() KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:971
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() Executors.java:511
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() FutureTask.java:266
java.lang.Thread.run() Thread.java:745

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-3-kafka-listener-1 State: WAITING tid: 25
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) Unsafe.java
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(Object, long) LockSupport.java:215
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(long, TimeUnit) LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer$ListenerInvoker.run() KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:971
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() Executors.java:511
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() FutureTask.java:266
java.lang.Thread.run() Thread.java:745
```

## Configuration Blueprints used in all three consumers

### Spring Integration XML

```
<bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties"
        id="containerProperties"
        c:topics="a_topic"
        p:ackMode="RECORD"
        p:ackOnError="false" />

<bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer"
        id="kafkaReceiverContainer"
        p:concurrency="4"
        c:consumerFactory-ref="consumerFactory"
        c:containerProperties-ref="containerProperties" />

<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
    listener-container="kafkaReceiverContainer"
    auto-startup="true"
    channel="kafkaInbound"
    phase="100"
    send-timeout="5000" />
```

### Java Config

```
  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, byte[]> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = constructConsumerProperties();
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, byte[]>(props);
  }
  private Map<String, Object> constructConsumerProperties() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.brokerAddress); // Kafka broker URLs. Doesn't need to be a complete list of brokers
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, this.consumerGroupId); // Consumer Group ID. Must be unique for every app. Multiple instances must have same ID.
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false); // We will use "RECORD" AckMode in the Spring Listener Container
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30_000); // Timeout to detect failures when using Kafka's group management facilities
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest"); // Start with the first message when a new consumer group (app) arrives at the topic
    if (sslEnabled) {
      props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
      props.put("ssl.keystore.location", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore"));
      props.put("ssl.keystore.password", System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword"));
    }
    return props;
  }
```

#Used versions

- Kafka Client Version 0.11.0.0
- Spring Kafka 1.2.2.RELEASE
- Spring Integration Kafka 2.1.0.RELEASE

#server.properties

```
auto.create.topics.enable=false
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
background.threads=10
broker.id=10001
broker.id.generation.enable=false
compression.type=producer
connections.max.idle.ms=600000
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms=5000
controller.socket.timeout.ms=30000
default.replication.factor=1
delete.topic.enable=true
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
group.max.session.timeout.ms=30000
group.min.session.timeout.ms=6000
inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.1.0
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
listeners=SSL://example-broker.biz:9092
log.cleaner.backoff.ms=15000
log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=86400000
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor=0.9
log.cleaner.io.buffer.size=524288
log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second=1.7976931348623157E308
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5
log.cleaner.threads=1
log.cleanup.policy=delete
log.dir=/srv/data/kafka/
log.index.interval.bytes=4096
log.index.size.max.bytes=10485760
log.message.format.version=0.10.1.0
log.preallocate=false
log.retention.bytes=-1
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=336
log.roll.hours=336
log.roll.jitter.hours=0
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.segment.delete.delay.ms=60000
max.connections.per.ip=2147483647
message.max.bytes=1000012
metrics.num.samples=2
metrics.sample.window.ms=30000
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=8
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
num.replica.fetchers=1
offset.metadata.max.bytes=4096
offsets.commit.required.acks=-1
offsets.commit.timeout.ms=5000
offsets.load.buffer.size=5242880
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms=600000
offsets.retention.minutes=2880
offsets.topic.compression.codec=0
offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
offsets.topic.segment.bytes=104857600
principal.builder.class=org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.DefaultPrincipalBuilder
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
queued.max.requests=16
quota.consumer.default=9223372036854775807
quota.producer.default=9223372036854775807
quota.window.num=11
quota.window.size.seconds=1
replica.fetch.backoff.ms=1000
replica.fetch.max.bytes=1048576
replica.fetch.min.bytes=1
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms=500
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms=5000
replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536
replica.socket.timeout.ms=30000
request.timeout.ms=30000
reserved.broker.max.id=100000
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.key.password=...
ssl.keymanager.algorithm=SunX509
ssl.keystore.location=/srv/kafka/current/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=...
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.protocol=TLS
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm=PKIX
ssl.truststore.location=/srv/kafka/current/ssl/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=...
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000
zookeeper.set.acl=false
zookeeper.sync.time.ms=2000
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.
If the consumer can't keep up; you'll get lag.
I don't know how you can expect the framework to help with that.

Comment: Okay we managed to reproduce the problem in a more simplistic way and started to monitor with yourkit

For the configuration we have 4x the two components:
- org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-x-kafka-listener-x
- org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-x-kafka-consumer-x

at some point in time one or more of the kafka-listeners are waiting indefinitely and their Threads stay in sun.misc.Unsafe.park(...) forever.

The question is why do they do that?

In my opinion even if the consumers are slow all the messages should be consumed eventually

Comment: `Unsafe.park()` can be called from many places; you would need to examine the complete stack to see where things are really stuck; also, often, looking at static stacks won't help much; you might have to turn on debug logging to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thank you @GaryRussell, I added a Stacktrace to the question see CONT

Comment: As I said; static analysis of stacks is often not enough; all that shows is the listener threads are waiting for data from the kafka consumer threads; DEBUG logging should be your next step.

Comment: Okay we have created a lot of DEBUG messages https://paste.ee/p/PJx0g but no clear evidence of the problem. Thread 24 (consumer -3) reads its last message here https://paste.ee/p/PJx0g#s=0&l=4497 and thread 26 (consumer -0) here https://paste.ee/p/PJx0g#s=0&l=4573. Both should consume further messages but start to get a lag.

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug in the kafka client's (or broker) pause/resume logic; we paused the consumer thread (`3-C-1`) at line 1290 (2 partitions) and resumed it at line 1647 but received no more data. The upcoming 1.3 release (currently 1.3.0.M2) has a simpler threading model, facilitated by KIP-62, where we no longer have to pause/resume the consumer with slow listeners.

Comment: @GaryRussell, could you please elaborate or link to the source mentioning this problem? 
is it a known bug?
we're facing a similar problem.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry; I was just looking at their logs and I believe we are doing everything correctly. If you can upgrade to 1.3.2.RELEASE it has a much simpler threading model and doesn't need to pause/resume the consumer thanks to KIP-62.

Comment: @VictorBouhnik we unluckily did not find any solution yet. We will do a new load test in a couple of weeks with the updated Broker and sources and hope this will fix the problem since it is very hard to narrow down.

Comment: @GaryRussell thanks